# SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number in Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer

Tags: node.js, ssl, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to run [Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) with a Hyperledger Fabric network setup using the [steps here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html). `composer-cli` works good. But when I run Blockchain Explorer with `node main.js` it returns following error

`16637 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.`

`composer-cli` is able to connect well with peers which means the SSL connection between `composer-cli` and peers is good. How do I fix the version of SSL running on blockchain explorer written in node.js ?

Comment: Hello Tushar, did you find a solution? I'm facing the same error

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did anybody find the solution?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry guys. I abandoned the problem after some trying. I am happy with my development environment of composer cli and fabric dev servers